# Protractor multiCapabilities with the same browser

Tags: google-chrome, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner

I am running protractor with 'multiCapabilities' as follows:

```
multiCapabilities : [
{  
  name : 'ChromeIphone',
  logName : 'Chrome Iphone',
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    'args': ['user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4']
  },
  mobileEmulationEnabled: true
},
{
  name : 'ChromeAndroid',
  logName : 'Chrome Android',
  platformName: 'android',
  browserName: 'chrome',
  newCommandTimeout: 60,
  chromeOptions: {
    'args': ['user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Samsung Galaxy S4 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36']
  }
}
],
```

This results in launching two instances of web drivers. When one of them fails I would like to know which one failed in the report which I have created.

I tried using the following function in 'onPrepare'.

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
  browser.name = (cap.browserName === undefined) ? (cap.caps_) ? cap.caps_.browserName : 'chrome' : cap.browserName;
  console.log('Current browser: ' + browser.name);
});
```

Which is kind of useless in my case since I am always using 'chrome' as a browser.

Is there any way in which at runtime I could know the user-agent being used? Or maybe it would be possible to know which one of my 'multiCapabilities' has failed?

Comment: with the getCapabilities you can retrieve browser name at runtime.
And which report are you using? In html-screenshot-reporter it clearly says where it failed.

Comment: I know about the browser name ... however, we are always using 'chrome' as browser with different user agents to simulate android, iphone etc. In the title of the report created I would like 'Android' or 'Iphone' visible. The reporter I am using is 'protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter'

Comment: oh ok, I don't think they are directly allowed, because they capture only the body of the browser. You need to customize the reports i guess. If you find a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values from the processed config file:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(currentConfig) {
        console.log('Current browser: ' + currentConfig.capabilities.name);

        // if you want to see all the properties, you can use this
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(currentConfig.capabilities, null, 4));
    });
};
```